# Service missing after upgrade Istio from 1.4.5 to 1.5.0

Tags: istio

I follow the instructions to use `istioctl upgrade` to upgrade my istio 1.4.5 installation to 1.5.0. It works fine, even passed `istioctl verify-install` check.

But when I launch the Kiali, it reports some errors in Istio configurations:

[image]

I checked the config there, and it looks like there is no istio-telemetry service:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `istio-telemetry` has been depreciated with the 1.5 release.

Please review the Upgrade Notes [page](https://istio.io/news/releases/1.5.x/announcing-1.5/upgrade-notes/) in istio `1.5` documentation.

Under [Mixer deprecation](https://istio.io/news/releases/1.5.x/announcing-1.5/upgrade-notes/#mixer-deprecation) section You can find:

> Mixer, the process behind the  `istio-telemetry`  and  `istio-policy`  deployments, has been deprecated with the 1.5 release.  `istio-policy`  was disabled by default since Istio 1.3 and  `istio-telemetry`  is disabled by default in Istio 1.5.
>
> Telemetry is collected using an in-proxy extension mechanism (Telemetry V2) that does not require Mixer.
>
> If you depend on specific Mixer features like out of process adapters, you may re-enable Mixer. Mixer will continue receiving bug fixes and security fixes until Istio 1.7. Many features supported by Mixer have alternatives as specified in the  Mixer Deprecation document including the  [in-proxy extensions](https://github.com/istio/proxy/tree/master/extensions)  based on the WebAssembly sandbox API.
>
> If you rely on a Mixer feature that does not have an equivalent, we encourage you to open issues and discuss in the community.
>
> Please check  Mixer Deprecation notice for details.
>
> #### Feature gaps between Telemetry V2 and Mixer Telemetry
>
> - Out of mesh telemetry is not supported. Some telemetry is missing if the traffic source or destination is not sidecar injected.
> - Egress gateway telemetry is  [not supported](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/19385).
> - TCP telemetry is only supported with  `mtls`.
> - Black Hole telemetry for TCP and HTTP protocols is not supported.
> - Histogram buckets are  [significantly different](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/20483)  than Mixer Telemetry and cannot be changed.

Note: I had to delete the short-links as Stack Overflow doesn't allow them.